what to do when two structs have Types of each other
Hi I am wondering what to do when two structs are dependent on each other. For example
module PolulationGenerator
  mutable struct Person
    id::Integer
    age::Integer
    current_location::Union{Place, nothing}
  end

  mutable Struct Place
    person::Person
    is_family::Bool
  end
end


Here both the struts depend on each other as Person has field "current_location" of type Place. While struct Place takes in field "person" of type Person. I am unable to place one struct over the other as they are both have fields of Type of each other. What should I do with a problem like this. I get the error UndefVarError" Place not defined

Julia does not (yet) have forward declaration of structs, so you cannot define the member of a struct to have a concrete type that is not yet fully defined. See this old but still active issue for more details.
The issue lists three ways to work around the issue of circular dependencies in struct definitions:
1. Use abstract type members
A struct can have a member of an abstract type, so you could do this:
abstract type AbstractPlace end

struct Person
  place::Union{Nothing, AbstractPlace}
end

struct Place <: AbstractPlace
  person::Person
end

person1 = Person(nothing)
place = Place(person1)
person2 = Person(place)

Because the place member of Person is abstract in this way, it is represented internally as a pointer to an object, meaning the member has to be dereferenced every time it is used, leading to a potential loss in efficiency.
2. Use parametric-typed parameters
You can parameterize the type of a struct member so that it is filled in at JIT compile time:
struct Person{PL}
  place::Union{Nothing, PL}
end

struct Place
  person::Person
end

# note that you have to tell the constructor what PL is
person1 = Person{Place}(nothing)
place = Place(person1)
person2 = Person(place)

Because the place member is of parameterized type, the compiler can treat it as a concrete member of Person and potentially avoid dereferencing pointers, leading to more optimized performance. However, this solution requires a little extra work when constructing instances of Person, and there may be some potential type confusion in your code given Person{PlaceA} != Person{PlaceB} for two different types PlaceA and PlaceB.
3. Break Julia (DO NOT DO THIS)
There is an interesting "feature" in current versions of Julia concerning how types are defined: if an error occurs in the middle of parsing a struct definition block, the struct's type remains available even if it isn't properly defined. That means you can do this (and possibly break many things along the way):
try
  struct Person
    place::Union{Nothing, Place}
  end
catch
end

# Person is a valid type name here, even though any attempts to make a Person will fail

struct Place
  person::Person
end

# Shockingly, Place is defined

struct Person
  place::Union{Nothing, Place}
end

# Now Person and Place are both defined (but could be broken)

You can read in the comments to the issue that this mechanism may lead to your program crashing unexpectedly, so I would consider it undefined behavior and avoid this kludge.
4. Maybe reconsider your data structures
As a final note, a Person struct with a member Place that has a member Person (that has a member Place that has a member...) could be represented with an external mapping of Person objects to Place objects (and vice versa). A Dict{Person,Place} (or, if you are using integer IDs, Dict{Int,Place}) could go a long way to addressing your needs, assuming you have the flexibility in your code to implement it.
